# PouchDB createIndex throws a 500 error code

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I am just trying to create a basic index like this

```js
currentDB.createIndex({
    index: {
        fields: ['name']
    }
}).then((result) => {
  
}).catch((error) => {

})
```

But it just sends me a 500 with an 'unknown_error' error message
[image]

I can successfully run all other methods: .getIndexes, .allDocs, .query etc... only this method is failing for some reason.

Comment: You're running on which browser, which PouchDB version, any adapter?

Comment: Using chrome, PouchDB version 6.4.3 and have also tried 6.2.0, no adapters

Comment: Have you try on different browser, clearing your cache?

Comment: I've tried different browsers and clearing cache, same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/basics.html#http-status-codes):

> 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> The request was invalid, either because the supplied JSON was invalid,
>   or invalid information was supplied as part of the request.

You need to provide more details to be able to re-produce your situation.

---

I tired the `createIndex` API on NodeJS to see if I run into any issue. I created the following code in a file named `server.js`:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"; // Ignore rejection, becasue CouchDB SSL certificate is self-signed

//import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb')
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'))
const db = new PouchDB('https://admin:****@192.168.1.106:6984/reproduce')

db.createIndex({
    index: {
        fields: ['title']
    }
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

When I run the code, the results are fine:

```
$ node server.js 
{ result: 'created',
  id: '_design/94407075806d27d94ac764d9aa138a43c015dc1f',
  name: '94407075806d27d94ac764d9aa138a43c015dc1f' }
```

So, at least on NodeJS, there shouldn't be any problem with `createIndex`. My PouchDB versions are shown below:

```
{
  "name": "reproduce-pouchdb-tls",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "pouchdb": "^6.4.3",
    "pouchdb-find": "^6.4.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What other information can I provide that would be helpful? This request only started to fail as of last week. I had been using it previously, and without any changes to the code on our side the request has begun failing.

Comment: @PandaScript To use [createIndex](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_index) you need pouchdb-find plugin. Which version of pouchdb-find plugin are you using?

Comment: @PandaScript I tried the `createIndex` API on NodeJS. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I actually get a different error when I try using createIndex on the server, I get createIndex does not exist! The .find method also does not work on the server for some reason.

Comment: @PandaScript Please compare your code on server-side with my code and see if there is any prominent difference.

Comment: So previously I was retrieving the database using superlogin and then performing the createIndex method on it. This gave me the 'createIndex' is not a function error. BUT when I retrieve the database from superlogin and then create a new instance of it with the "db = new PouchDB(db)" method, it works. Can you explain why?

Comment: @PandaScript I'm not sure why. I didn't work with superlogin before.